# Transparent components list background in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using custom installer to build "my own" setup.

Is it possible to create transparent background or disable background on components list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colour, border style, etc of the component list so you can handle any solid background colour, but not make it transparent.
`WizardForm.ComponentsList` is a `TNewCheckListBox` for which you can see all properties in the *"Support Classes Reference"* in the help.