# Show background behind controls on custom page of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I've created an installer, and I'm trying to set an image for the background. But the background does not show behind the text and progress bar controls on installation page, here is how it looks:

[image: InstallTypePage]
[image: InstallingPage]

And this is the code I use to set background:

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFile('white.bmp');

InstallTypePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpSelectDir,
  '', '',
  'Si eliges la instalación de tipo "Servidor" se creará una base de datos en blanco.',
  True, False);
{add white background}
BackImageW := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
BackImageW.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\white.bmp'));
BackImageW.Top := 0;
BackImageW.Left := 0; 
BackImageW.Parent := InstallTypePage.Surface;
BackImageW.Align := alCLient; 
BackImageW.Stretch := False;

{create radio buttons on page}
InstallTypePageID := InstallTypePage.ID;
InstallTypePage.Add('Servidor');
InstallTypePage.Add('Terminal');
InstallTypePage.Add('Restablecer');

BackImageW := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
BackImageW.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\white.bmp'));
BackImageW.Top := 0;
BackImageW.Left := 0;
BackImageW.Parent := WizardForm.InstallingPage;
BackImageW.Align := alCLient;
BackImageW.Stretch := False;
WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top := WizardForm.InstallingPage.Height - ScaleY(40);
WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height := ScaleY(8);
```

Comment: sorry, I dont test in Windows 7 before I post, I edit my question, I see its my code that doesn't works.

Comment: Sorry again, I edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TNewStaticText` does not support transparency. You can fix that by replacing it with `TLabel`. See [Inno Setup - Transparency under text in page name and description labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46178215/850848).

But your problem is not only `TNewStaticText`, but also `TNewCheckListBox` and other controls. And `TNewCheckListBox` does not support transparency at all. See [Transparent components list background in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6726640/850848) All you can do is to set its background to white. And if you decide to rely on this approach anyway, you can do the same with `TNewStaticText` and all other controls.

```
InstallTypePage.SubCaptionLabel.Color := clWhite;
InstallTypePage.CheckListBox.Color := clWhite;
```

[image]

---

You cannot change a color of `TNewProgressBar` though. You would have to draw a custom progress bar. See [How do I change the color of my progress bar in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33630532/850848)

---

There are clones of Inno Setup with themeing support. Those may support transparency of these controls.

Comment: Im goint to see  `How do I change the color of my progress bar in Inno Setup?` too, thank you very much Martin.